# Calculus Applications: rate of increase

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a student, studying engineering. I have a calculus exam on Monday and this question is from a past paper and is one of the concepts that challenge me.

A new wonderful computer comes on the market. The rate of increase in numbers of people $x$ who own one is proportional to the product of $x$ and $(N-x)$, where $N$ is a constant. Given that initially $x = (1/10)N$, and that after one week of aggressive selling $x = N/4$.

1. Show that after $t$ weeks, $x/(N-x) = 3^{t-2}$.
2. Find the time at which $3/N$ people own one of these computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation involves the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda x(N-x)$$
which has solution $$\frac{1}{N}\ln \frac{x}{N-x}=\lambda t+C.$$

Putting in the initial conditions, $x=\frac{N}{10}$ when $t=0$ and $x=\frac{N}{4}$ when $t=1$ gives $$\frac{1}{N}\ln \frac{1}{9}=C, \frac{1}{N}\ln \frac{1}{3}=\lambda +C.$$
With a little algebra we then obtain $\lambda=\frac{1}{N}\ln 3.$

Substituting all this gives the particular solution $$\frac{1}{N}\ln \frac{x}{N-x}=(\frac{1}{N}\ln 3) t+\frac{1}{N}\ln \frac{1}{9}$$
which simplifies to $$\ln \frac{x}{N-x}=(\ln 3) t+\ln \frac{1}{9}=\ln 3^t+\ln 3^{-2}=\ln 3^{t-2}.$$

We  have thus obtained the answer to part (i) i.e.
$$\frac{x}{N-x}= 3^{t-2}.$$

**N.B. I'm assuming there is a typo in part (ii) of the question.** The number of people should presumably be a fraction of the form $\frac{N}{a}$. Whatever it is, simply substitute it for $x$ and solve for $t$.